# Recover address from signature works only with MetaMask

Tags: signature, keccak, php, elliptic

I try to implement Web3 login to my page. It works with MetaMask, but with other wallets (like LRC, Coinbase or Argent) it doesn't - recovered address differs from the original one.

[Ethereum\EcRecover](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ecverify) package does all the crypto work here.

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Ethereum\EcRecover;

$message = "Sign this message to validate that \nyou are the owner of the account. \n\nRandom string: 624ed7b003d9d";
$signature = '0x5bd34199cfcf1c4f374bd983a2c0a50ae76ea9cc41df2d70ec306a671352d42d45a819b1fd28090aa1ddd895d6f4ecbdd9715d4f31ae0b410ff00d12e2c34f5a1b';
$address = '0x1a44ba4b1C7bd22b896B76d4776dB3f6C541fb60'; // Safe address from test wallet

$recoveredAddress = EcRecover::personalEcRecover($message, $signature);

if ($recoveredAddress === $address) {
    echo "Verified\n";
} else {
    echo "Recovered address differs from the original one\n";
    echo "Original address:  $address\n";
    echo "Recovered address: $recoveredAddress\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EcRecover::personalVerifyEcRecover will always return a wallet address in lower case. You are comparing a lower cased wallet address and a mix cased wallet address.

Your comparison should look like this
if ($recoveredAddress === strtolower($address))

The reason why it's working with metamask is because metamask returns a lower cased wallet address while other wallet may return a mix cased wallet address hence failing your comparison.